# I want to include a closing bracket } in a \newcommand definition

Tags: macros

I want to use the closing bracket in a `\newcommand` definition. I can give more explanation as to why, but this seems unnecessary at the moment. Obviously the MWE does not work, but how to make this work?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\test}{somecommand}}

\begin{document}
Hi 
\end{document}
```

which gives the error

```
! Too many }'s.
```

Comment: Do you want to end a group, or do you want to display the `}`?

Comment: End a group. I have another command with an opening bracket, some text in between and then a command with a closing bracket (the one I am asking about now).

Comment: then why not use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to begin and end groups in such circumstances.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand\test{sheep \egroup}
\begin{document}
Pig \bgroup\Huge\test goat
\end{document}
```

[image]