# Opening and closing brackets in combination with the ifthen package

Tags: macros, conditionals

Related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207639/i-want-to-include-a-closing-bracket-in-a-newcommand-definition), however, I was not able to solve my problem.

Let me give some background. I want to switch between the article style and a specific journal style. The journal style has specific commands that it uses for the abstract, proofs, appendices, etc. The variable `\var` states if I use the article style (0) or the journal style (1). Let us assume the command `\ABSTRACT` is used by the journal and it takes one argument as the actual abstract. So, normally you would print your abstract as `\ABSTRACT{This is my abstract.}`.

The following MWE does not work, and the error is that it is missing a closing argument }.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\var}{1}
\newcommand{\ABSTRACT}[1]{\begin{abstract}#1\end{abstract}}

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\var = 1}{\ABSTRACT\bgroup}{\begin{abstract}}%
This is my abstract.%
\ifthenelse{\var = 1}{\egroup}{\end{abstract}}%

Some other text below the abstract.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is why people asked why you wanted the bracket in eh other question, you said you wanted a group. But macro argument delimiters do not form a group and have to be `{}` explicitly they can not be `\bgroup`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macro delimiter braces have to be explicit catcode  1 and 2 characters, (typically `{}`) they can not be `\bgroup\egroup`.  You can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\var}{1}
\newcommand{\ABSTRACT}[1]{\begin{abstract}#1\end{abstract}}

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\var = 1}
{\newcommand\myabstract[1]{\ABSTRACT{#1}}}
{\newcommand\myabstract[1]{\begin{abstract}#1\end{abstract}}}


\myabstract{This is my abstract.}

Some other text below the abstract.

\end{document}
```